# Why does VS warn me that typeof(T) is never the provided type in a generic method where the type parameter is restricted to implement T?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, type-parameter

I hope the question is correct, so let's give you an example. Imagine the following generic method:

```
public abstract class Base : IDisposable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>()
        where T : Base
    {
        // To ensure T inherits from Base.
        if (typeof(T) is Base)
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        // ...
    }
}
```

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/bb384067.aspx) the keyword `where` restricts the type parameter `T` to be of type `Base` or to inherit from this class.

> [...] a where clause can include a base class constraint, which states that a type must have the specified class as a base class (or be that class itself) in order to be used as a type argument for that generic type.

Also this code does compile:

```
public static T GetFirst()
    where T : Base
{
    // Call GetList explicitly using Base as type parameter.
    return (T)GetList<Base>().First();
}
```

So when following the last code `typeof(T)` should return `Base`, shouldn't it? Why does Visual Studio then prints this warning to me?

> warning CS0184: The given expression is never of the provided ('Demo.Base') type.

Comment: What do you want to do? Ensuring that `T` inherits from `Base` is useless, since the generic constrain already ensures that.

Comment: The constraint ensures that `T` either inherits from `Base` **OR** is `Base` itself. I want `T` only to inherit from `Base`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`typeof(whatever)` always returns an instance of type `Type`. `Type` doesn't derive from `Base`.

What you want is this:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(Base))
    throw new NotSupportedException("Please specify a type derived from Base");
```

Something that looks like it is the same is this:

```
if(variableOfTypeT is Base)
```

But that has a different meaning.
The first statement (with `typeof(Base)`) only is `true` if `T` is  `Base`. It will be `false` for any type derived from `Base`.
The second statement (`variableOfTypeT  is Base`) is always `true` in your class, because any class derived from `Base` will return `true` for a check for its base class.

Comment: The alternative doesn't work... `T` is a type parameter but is used like a variable ;) But the first approach works... How did I miss that?! Sometimes the solution is too simple :D

Answer (score 4):

That's not how you check inheritance.

`typeof(T)` is of type `System.Type`, it's not `Base`. To see if T is derived from Base you should use the [IsSubclassOf method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx), like this:

```
if(typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base))  ...
```

Comment: Note that will returns `false` if `T==Base`

Comment: I thought that was the point. Because of the restriction, OP already knows T is either Base or derived from it.

Comment: I wanted to know if `T` *is* `Base` to make sure only implementations of that abstract class get passed to the method. `IsSubclassOf` would perform the check I already have expressed with the `where` constraint.